# I wonder about crc error probability. How can I get 2^(-n)?

Tags: crc, crc32, crc16, error-detection

I wonder about crc error probability.

In most papers, crc error rate is described like 1-2<sup>(-n)</sup>

For example, the probability of crc-16 is 1-2<sup>(-16)</sup>,
so 2<sup>(-16)</sup>=1∕65536=0.0015%, prob = 99.9984%

I want to know how I can get this formula: 2^<sup>(-n)</sup>.

If 2<sup>(-n)</sup> is correct rate, the rate of crc-16 and crc-ccitt is same?
And if message bit is bigger than before, the rate is same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an *n*-bit CRC, there are 2<sup>*n*</sup> possible values of that CRC. Therefore the probability that a message with random errors applied, regardless of the length of the message (so long as it's four bytes or more), has the same CRC as the original message is 2<sup>-*n*</sup>. This true for *any* hash function, including any variant of a CRC, that mixes the input bits well into the output.